# Parent component displaying twice same child component with different inputs display only one of the input

Tags: angular

Let's say i have a parent component that contains twice the same component with two different inputs :

```
  <div class="row">
    <app-contact class="col m6 xs12" [contactForm]="mainContactForm" [model]="mainContact"></app-contact>

    <app-contact class="col m6 xs12" [contactForm]="associationContactForm"  [model]="associationContact" [hidden]="isAssociationContactHidden"></app-contact>
  </div>
```

Child component gets the form and the model :

```
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {
@Input() public contactForm: FormGroup;
@Input() private model: ContactModel;
```

In the OnInit implemented method :

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

fields.forEach((control: FormControl, name: string) => {
  if (name.startsWith('ContactModel')) {
    name = name.split('-')[1];
    // Sets the default value from the model
    control.setValue(this.model[name]);
    this.contactForm.addControl(name, control);
  }
});

...
```

Consoles shows that the 'control.setValue(this.model[name])' puts the correct value in the control.

Rev. 1 : In the parent component, both forms are created same way :

```
      this.mainContactForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
      this.associationContactForm = this.formBuilder.group({});
```

In the ngOnInit method of the parent component.

But, when Angular shows :

[image: Same datas on both formGroup]

As you can see, same datas on both two different formGroup.

What's wrong with this approach ?

Regards

Comment: what is the reason to set 'private' to input 'model'? could it be the reason?

Comment: No reason except i'dont need model outside the component itself

Comment: Please also include the code which creates `mainContactForm` and `associationContactForm`

Comment: Both forms are created from FormBuilder.group() method at parent component initialization.